# Is there a function to stack multiple duplicate dataframes

Tags: r

Just wondering if there was a function that could stack the same dataframe multiple times.
Here is an example whereby I stack same dataframe three times on top of each other.

```
df <- mtcars

df <- rbind(df,df,df) # here stack same df three times
```

Is there a function that can stack the same dataframes mulitple times, where you only need specify the number of times to be duplicated. I could write a loop to do it, but is there function that can do it like this

```
df <- stack(df , 3) # does a function like this exist?
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in a package that I know of, but you can do this either in a one liner, or create a custom function.

Custom function:

```
stack_df <- function(dataframe, ntimes) {
  as.data.frame(sapply(dataframe, rep.int, times = ntimes))
}
stack_df(dataframe = mtcars, ntimes = 3)
```

One liner:

```
as.data.frame(sapply(mtcars, rep.int, times = 3))
```

Comment: That's a very nice way to do it (better than a loop). Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

We may use `replicate`

```
stack_df <- function(data, n) 
   {
    do.call(rbind, replicate(n, data, simplify = FALSE))

}
```

-testing

```
out <- stack_df(mtcars, 3)
> dim(out)
[1] 96 11
```